# How many ways can the 10 chairs be distributed?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have a question about the basic counting problem.

Situation : There are 50 people and 10 chairs in the room. Among them, 5 chairs are already assigned the special 5 people of the 50 people. In this situation, how many ways can the 10 chairs be distributed? (each chair is not distinguishable)

My answer : I thought that 45 x 44 x 43 x 42 x 41, since 5 chairs are already assigned. So, except for 5 people who have their chairs, among 45 people, we can distribute the left 5 chairs to them.

Is this correct?

Any comments would be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: If the chairs are not distinguishable, you need to divide that number by 5!. This is same as choosing 5 people from 45 people.

Comment: I see. But, I'm so confused of this question because of the special 5 people. Could you give me any explanation how to deal with the special 5 people in this problem?

Comment: Since the special people are already assigned and the chairs are not distinguishable, they need not be counted. We need to choose 5 people for the other chairs only.