# How many ways can the 10 A's be distributed?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm stuck with the basic counting problem.

Problem is the following:

> Corrupt professor Z has a class of 50 students. He needs to give exactly 10 A's. However five students already have a special deal (they are professor Z's nephews and neices) and will get A's for sure. How many ways can the 10 A's be distributed?

My thought : 45 Choose 5, because we can ignore 5 people(nephews and nieces) who will get A's grade for sure.

I'm not sure my thought is correct or not. I'm appreciated any comment or explanation for this.

Comment: You are right. If five A's are already given away, that leaves 45 people to give 5As to.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909106/how-many-ways-can-the-10-chairs-be-distributed

Comment: @HenrySwanson I'm voting to close that one as a duplicate of this one, because that doesn't have an accepted answer so you can't close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is 45 Choose 5 because you have 5 As and a population of 45 students to give it to.

Comment: Let me check a minor issue in this problem. since the grade A's are not distinguishable, so that it cause 45 Choose 5. Is this also correct?

Comment: Yes.  Because the A's are not distinguishable it makes it a "Choose"

Comment: Specifically: What you are *choosing* are five from forty-five *distinct students* to receive the A-marks.  The A-marks not being distinguishable (nor the 40 other marks) means you *don't* have to count arrangements among themselves.